# Pycharm/Django indentation error

Tags: django, pycharm

I was asked in Pycharm some question along the lines of 'your code was was written with 4 spaces rather than tabs, press ok' but I cannot remember the exact wording.  I didn't know what the option meant but since I pressed that button I'm getting an ident error.  But I do not get an ident error in other locations.  Now I'm getting an indentation error at 'list_display_links' and the code looks just the same as it does on this tutorial.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

class PostModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["title", "updated", "timestamp"]
    list_display_links = ['updated']
    class Meta:
        model = Post
```

[tutorial image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VE3hc.png)

Answer (score 1):

I had to hit reformat code on Pycharm, as seen here:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm follows [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) so it will notify you about code not indented properly (read about [pep 8 indentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation))

When you use pycharm feature of reformat code it will modify your code with pep 8 guideline such as indentation with 4 spaces, import statements, line spacing after class/function single space after comma space before and after `=` at variable assignment, it will also wrap code with [Maximum line length of 79 characters](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length) and many more